# Is there a way to schedule Javascript on Sharepoint online environment

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there any way to schedule a javascript for Sharepoint site?
Actually we are using Sharepoint Online environment and are not allowed to deploy any custom code on the site. hence cannot use Timer jobs/workflows.

Please provide any suggestions on how we can schedule the Javascript for Office 365(Sharepoint Online) site.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Since Javascript is client-based, I don't think it's possible unless you keep a browser open (on a server maybe) that does this.
What exactly are you trying to to, that you would want in a timerjob?

FYI... It's possible to deploy sandboxed solutions to SharePoint Office 365. In there you can create your own custom workflow code which can be used inside Sharepoint Designer.